# Set the Visitor ID in Adobe Analytics through DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to set the Visitor ID in Adobe Analytics through DTM.

Above the s_code I have:

```
var visitor = new Visitor("xxxx") 
visitor.trackingServer = "xxx.xx.xx.omtrdc.net"
```

I've created a data element where the legacy code used to call the

```
Visitor.getInstance("xxxx");
```

and set the Visitor ID to `%Visitor ID%`

That's not working however, and my visitor ID is always just set to %Visitor ID% and obviously not reading any values. I'd really appreciate any input that someone can give me.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Visitor ID** pops `s.visitorID` and is in general related to visitor id, but is not the same as `s.visitor` which is what gets popped for the VisitorAPI integration.  DTM does not currently have a built-in field for the `s.visitor` variable, so you will have to set it yourself within the config, either in the **Library Management** code editor (assuming you are opting to c/p the core lib and not the "Managed by Adobe" option) or else in the **Custom Page Code** section.

Since you are popping it in a data layer first, you can reference the data layer like this:

`s.visitor = _satellite.getVar('Visitor ID');`

**NOTE:** A separate potential issue you may have is with whether or not the `Visitor` object is available for your data element. Since data elements are the first thing to be evaluated by DTM, you will need to ensure that the `VisitorAPI.js` library is output *before* your top page DTM script include.

If this is a problem for you, or if you are wanting to host `VisitorAPI.js` within DTM, then you may need to adjust where you are popping that stuff.  For example, place the  VisitorAPI core code above the custom code as the first stuff within the data element, before:

`var visitor = new Visitor("xxxx") visitor.trackingServer = "xxx.xx.xx.omtrdc.net`

Or, don't use the data element at all. Instead, put the VisitorAPI code within the Adobe Analytics custom code or core lib section and pop all that stuff (aboove the `s.visitor` assignment).  Or a number of other methods; point is, VisitorAPI stuff must be loaded before the data element can make use of it, same as it must be loaded before Adobe Analytics can make use of it.

Comment: Thank you. When I wrote these questions I was really hoping that you would see them. I appreciate all of your DTM and AA knowledge and it's really helped me with some of the other issues I've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

So DTM is changing pretty fast and furious right now. They have a "Marketing Cloud Service ID" that works well. Before I used that, however, I did find a way to fix the code. Crayon Violent was right, as usual, that the problem was that the script wasn't available yet. I fixed this by putting the following code in between the VisitorAPI.js and the AppMeasurement stuff in the DTM managed library.

```
var aA = new AppMeasurement();
aA.visitorNamespace="companyname";
aA.visitor = Visitor.getInstance("companyname");
```

In addition, there were also some issues using my localhost for testing while trying to see if I had this correct or not. If you are having issues and think you have it correct, it may be worthwhile to elevate it to a different environment.